# How to post list of objects eg:- List<products> through a table which is inside a form in thymeleaf?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

this is my html:
when I am seeing the preview in intelliJ of the same page, it is showing the right page but as soon as I run my program the and click on addInvoice button it is just showing the fields which are above the table only ....the table inputs are not showing in browser.The problem is inside`<tr th:each product...>`

```
   <input type="hidden" th:field="*{primaryKey}"
               placeholder="primaryKey" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">

        <input type="text" th:field="*{invoiceNo}"
               placeholder="invoiceNo" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">
          ....
          ....
       <table border="1" class="table table-striped table-responsive-md">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>SNo</th>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Qty</th>
                    <th>Tax%</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                    
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr th:each="product,listOfProductsStat:*{listOfProducts}">

                    <td th:text="${listOfProductsStat.count}">1</td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{listOfProducts[__${listOfProductsStat.index}__].productName}">

                    </td>

                    <td>
                         <textarea class="form-control rounded-0" name="description" id="description" rows="3"
                                   maxlength="500"
                                   placeholder="Description"
                                   th:field="*{listOfProducts[__${listOfProductsStat.index}__].description}"></textarea>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="number" name="price" id="price" class="form-control"
                               th:field="*{listOfProducts[__${listOfProductsStat.index}__].price}" placeholder="Price">
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="number" name="qty" class="form-control" id="qty" placeholder="Qty"
                               th:field="*{listOfProducts[__${listOfProductsStat.index}__].qty}">
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="number" name="taxPercent" class="form-control" id="taxPercent" placeholder="Tax(%)"
                               th:field="*{listOfProducts[__${listOfProductsStat.index}__].taxPercent}">
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="number" name="total" class="form-control" id="total" placeholder="Total"
                               th:field="*{listOfProducts[__${listOfProductsStat.index}__].total}">
                   
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

this is my entities:

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

public class InvoiceInfo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long primaryKey;
    //    private int SNo;
    private String invoiceNo;
    private String billTo;
    private String status;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date invoiceDate;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date dueDate;
    private double grandTotal;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "invoiceInfo",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Product> listOfProducts=new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long productId;
    private String productName;
    private String description;
    private double price;
    private int qty;
    private int taxPercent;
    private double total;
//    private double subTotal;
//    private int totalTax;

//    private String invoiceNote;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_info_primary_key")
    private InvoiceInfo invoiceInfo;
```

this is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class InvoiceInfoController {
    @Autowired
    private InvoiceInfoService invoiceInfoService;

    @GetMapping("")
    public String InvoiceInfoListPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("InvoiceInfoList", invoiceInfoService.getAllInvoiceInfo());
        model.addAttribute("products",invoiceInfoService.getAllProducts());
        return "Home";
    }

    @GetMapping("/openNewInvoiceInfoForm")
    public String openNewInvoiceInfoForm(Model model) {
        InvoiceInfo invoiceInfo = new InvoiceInfo();
        model.addAttribute("invoiceInfo", invoiceInfo);
        return "new_invoiceInfo";
    }

    @PostMapping("saveInvoice")
    public String saveInvoiceInfo(@ModelAttribute("invoiceInfo") InvoiceInfo invoiceInfo) {
        invoiceInfoService.saveInvoiceInfo(invoiceInfo);
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @GetMapping("/editInvoiceForm/{primaryKey}")
    public String editInvoiceForm(@PathVariable(value = "primaryKey") long primaryKey , Model model) {
        InvoiceInfo invoiceInfo= invoiceInfoService.getInvoiceByPrimaryKey(primaryKey);
        model.addAttribute("invoiceInfo",invoiceInfo);
        return "update_invoiceInfo";
    }
    @GetMapping("/deleteInvoiceByPrimaryKey/{primaryKey}")
    public String deleteInvoiceByPrimaryKey(@PathVariable(value = "primaryKey") long primaryKey){
            this.invoiceInfoService.deleteInvoiceByPrimaryKey(primaryKey);
            return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

the problem:
`<tr th:each="product,listOfProductsStat:*{listOfProducts}">`
my code is not even showing the `<td>`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdaW1.png) tags in browser ..

How should I associate the listOfProducts instance in InvoiceInfo class with the form inputs and save it in Product table one by one?
Please help!